# Use of unresolved identifier 'userUid'; did you mean 'UserUid'? and Use of unresolved identifier 'destination'; did you mean 'description'?

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting up a login function but I keep getting 2 errors in this code on the `destination.userUid` line and the `destination.passwordField` line.

The errors are:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'userUid'; did you mean 'UserUid'?
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'destination'; did you mean 'description'?

I am learning to code so any advice would be appreciated.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toSignUp" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC {
            
            if (self.UserUid != nil) {
                destination.userUid = userUid
            }
            if self.emailField.text != nil {
                destination.emailField = emailField.text}
            }
    
        if self.passwordField.text != nil {
            destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact and complete `prepare` method. The code you posted isn't indented correctly nor does it have a full set of matching curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error messages. For the first error, you mistyped the variable name, instead of:

```
destination.userUid = userUid
```

use

```
destination.userUid = UserUid
```

For the second error, it seems like you missed a closing bracket in your code. The `if self.passwordField.text != nil` statement should be inside that `if let` statement.

Comment: Also there is no need to check if `UITextField`'s `text` property is `nil`, because it has `@""` set by default, so he should check if `text` isn't empty.

Comment: no it's right to double check , who knows the op may assigned nil for it or from other settings

Comment: @Sh_Khan try to set `text` property to `nil` and then try to print it, you get `""`.

Answer (score -1):

One more way to resolve this as,

```
if let userId = self.UserUid {
    destination.userUid = userId
}
```